# Does zero covariance imply independence of random variables here?

Tags: probability-theory

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Both are distributed according to $N(0,1)$. If their covariance is 0, are they independent?

I know that this is not true for other distributions, say the Wikipedia example: $X$ chosen uniformly in $[-1,1]$ and $Y=X^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.